# Error system library:fopen:No such process

Tags: php, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm starting to use this library https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle
When I use the command `php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair`, the console shows this error

> In GenerateKeyPairCommand.php line 151:
>
> error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process

I have Symfony 5 with PHP 7.1 and Openssl is running.

Answer (score 16):

You can override this command by manual action like in oldest version:

```
mkdir -p config/jwt
openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
openssl pkey -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem -pubout
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

just go to tags then go to the previous version where you will get these commend lines

`$ mkdir -p app/var/jwt`

`$ openssl genrsa -out app/var/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096`

`$ openssl rsa -pubout -in app/var/jwt/private.pem -out app/var/jwt/public.pem`

You can update the directories as you see fits, and
as you already know it's always better to not commit those generated keys to your repository.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case I just needed to install OpenSSL and reboot my pc and it worked.

Comment: After i reboot my pc, everythings worked

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the error `error:80000003:system library::No such process` on **Windows 10/11** when trying to run the command `php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair` with Lexik, you can follow these steps to resolve the issue:

1. Install the OpenSSL (light version) from [this link](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).
2. Add the path to your OpenSSL binary (`C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin` in this example) to the system environment variables. This allows your system to recognize the `openssl` command.
3. Open a new command line window and type `openssl` to check if the installation is successful. This step ensures that the `openssl` command is recognized globally.
4. Retry the command `php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair` in a new command line window.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the `error:80000003:system library::No such process` issue on Windows 10/11 when generating a key pair with Lexik.