# OpenSsl is taking ages to generate

Tags: symfony, openssl, rsa, symfony5

```
$ openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
....................++++
...............................................................++++
```

And stuck here since an hour.

I'm using following bundle in symfony 5.3

```
composer require "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle"
```

When I ran below command I got following error:

```
$ php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair
```

> [critical] Error thrown while running command
> ""lexik:jwt:generate-keypair"". Me ssage: "There are no commands
> defined in the "lexik:jwt" namespace."
>
> There are no commands defined in the "lexik:jwt" namespace.

So I ran following Commands but taking ages but didn't generate the keys.

```
openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096
openssl rsa -pubout -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem
```

Comment: can you check if u have     Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle::class => ['all' => true],
in your config/bundles.php  please

Comment: Yes the bundle is registered.

Comment: you can avoid this by using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66261466/14003393

Comment: Yes, i tried this exact same but it stuck.

Comment: well it's weird, can you please remove "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle" then require it

Comment: Created new project same issue

Comment: can you try this command php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair with sudo

Comment: Adding winpty before openssl did a job thanks Ouss.

Comment: you can also use sudo chmod 775 -R yourProject/ to avoid using sudo evry time